# Javascript check for completion of long running task in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using EXTJS 4.0 framework, running browsers (IE7/8/9, FF,Chrome) I have some reports that my system is running. I use the following code block to check if the report is finished:

```
// check for report finished
for (int i = 0; i < 480; i++) {
    UtilityMethods.log(con, "N", "DEBUG", reportNumber, message, null, null);
    ExecuteFunction statusEf = new ExecuteFunction(con, "pkg_report.check_queued_report_status");
    statusEf.setParam("p_report_number", reportNumber);
    statusEf.setParam("p_instance_number", instanceNumber);
    statusEf.setParam("p_wait_time", "60"); // wait 60 seconds
    status = statusEf.execute();
    // anything but timeout means the report is done
    if (!"TIMEOUT".equals(status) || SmsGlobals.smsShutdownFlag) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This works fine for shorter reports, but on longer reports the page displays "loading" long after the report has actually finished. I need to figure out a better way to check for the report to be finished. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: `ExecuteFunction statusEf = ...` is Javascript? Also, this looks like synchronous code, that's not Javascript either? This looks really weird. You wait 60 secs up to 480 times?

Comment: This looks like C# code calling into IronRuby or something. Are you sure it's JavaScript?

Comment: This is built in EXTJS framework. I didn't write the code, I was just hired to fix it. I was told it was JS, but I agree, it doesn't look like any javascript I've ever worked with. Hence the confusion and the problems finding a workaround.